# AEM6 (CQ) sightly passing through variable via template into javascript

Tags: templates, aem, sightly

I'm using the new sightly language in AEM6 to render my components using templates, in my component there is a video that uses the JWPlayer plugin which needs the following code to initalise the video:

```
<div id='playerpwSIOjcRZrCa'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerpwSIOjcRZrCa').setup({
        file: '//www.youtube.com/watch?v=123456',
        title: 'Video title',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
</script>
```

But I want to make the Youtube variable dynamic so the user can change the id within the author so have got the following template passing in the videoPath (youtube id):

```
<template data-sly-template.player="${@ videoPath}">

    Video Id: ${videoPath}

    <script src="//jwpsrv.com/library/HjcD1BZoEeS7ByIAC0MJiQ.js"></script>

    <div id='playerpwSIOjcRZrCa'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('playerpwSIOjcRZrCa').setup({
            file: '//www.youtube.com/watch?v=' ${videoPath},
            title: 'Video title',
            width: '100%',
            aspectratio: '16:9'
        });
    </script>

</template>
```

The problem I'm having is the ${videoPath} in the  tags is not rendering the id where as the one at the top of the template is.

Is there a way in solving this using the sightly templates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sightly contains out-of-the-box XSS protection. It detects that you are trying to inject `videoPath` variable inside the `<script>` tag and requires to specify the *context*, so it can escape special characters. In this case it should be `scriptString` context:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerpwSIOjcRZrCa').setup({
        file: '//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoPath @ context="scriptString"}',
        title: 'Video title',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
</script>
```

More info can be found in the [Adobe docs](http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/sightly.html#Display%20Context).

Comment: Tomek, I've tried your recommendation of '//www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoPath}' but still not adding the videoId to the end of the string.

Comment: You are right, I missed the point in my original answer. Please check the updated version.